# How to apply Green formula?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

I want to apply the Green formula two times in this integral:

$$\int_0^{+\infty} (r(t) u^{(3)}(t))' v(t) dt $$ such that $u(0)=u'(0)=0$, $v(0)=v'(0)=0, u(+\infty)=u'(+\infty)=0, v(+\infty)=v'(+\infty)=0$

the first time it gives: $$\int_0^{\infty}(r(t) u^{(3)}(t))' v(t) dt=-\int_0^{+\infty} r(t) u^{(3)}(t) v'(t) dt$$

and the second time it gives

$$\int_0^{\infty}(r(t) u^{(3)}(t))' v(t) dt=-\int_0^{+\infty} r(t) u^{(3)}(t) v'(t) dt=\int_0^{+\infty}r'(t) u''(t)v''(t) dt$$

is it correct ?

Answer (score 1):

In short: No.

Since you are integrating one-dimensional functions, Green's formula reduces to the simple integration by parts formula:
$$
\int\limits_a^b x y' = xy\Big|_a^b - \int\limits_a^b x'y,
$$
whenever functions $x$ and $y$ are absolutely continuous, with $y$ Lebesgue-integrable… or let's just say well defined and differentiable.

Applying this to your case, define $x(t) := v(t)$ and $y(t) := r(t) u^{(3)}(t)$. Hence,
$$
\int\limits_0^{+\infty} \big( r(t) u^{(3)}(t) \big)' v(t) \, dt = \int\limits_0^{+\infty} y'(t) x(t) \, dt = y(t) x(t) \Big|_0^{+\infty} - \int\limits_0^{+\infty} x'(t) y(t) \,dt;
$$
but $v(0)=u(+\infty)=v(+\infty)=0$, and supposing that $r$ is well-behaved enough (I would suggest *bounded*), then 
$$
\int\limits_0^{+\infty} \big( r(t) u^{(3)}(t) \big)' v(t) \, dt =  -\int\limits_0^{+\infty} v'(t) r(t) u^{(3)}(t) \,dt.
$$
This is what you got before, but again I advise you to take care on whether the limit $\displaystyle \lim_{t\to +\infty} r(t)v(t)u^{(3)}(t)$ is well defined.

Now, you got three choices here.

1. If $v$ and $r$ are *regular*, then you could define $x(t):=v'(t) r(t)$ and $y(t) := u''(t)$, then 
   $$
   \int\limits_0^{+\infty} r(t) v'(t) u^{(3)}(t) \, dt = r(t)v'(t) u''(t) \Big|_{0}^{+\infty} - \int\limits_0^{+\infty} \big(r'(t)v'(t) + r(t) v''(t) \big) u''(t) \, dt,
   $$
   where again you can use the fact that $v'(0) = v'(+\infty)=0$ and, as $r$ is regular, you may conclude
   $$
   \int\limits_0^{+\infty} \big( r(t) u^{(3)}(t) \big)' v(t) \, dt = \int\limits_0^{+\infty} \big(r'(t)v'(t) + r(t) v''(t) \big) u''(t) \, dt.
   $$
   As this is the case that you developed, remember the chain rule!
2. If $r$ is not regular enough but $v$ is, then you cannot consider a derivative of $r$. Define $x(t) := v'(t)$ and $y'(t) := r(t) u^{(3)}(t)$. Thus,
   $$
   \int\limits_0^{+\infty} v'(t) r(t) u^{(3)}(t) \, dt = v(t) y(t) \Big|_0^{+\infty} - \int\limits_0^{+\infty} v''(t) y(t) \, dt.
   $$
   Here you must find a primitive of $y'(t)$. By means of the integration by parts formula, you get that
   $$
   \int\limits_0^t y'(s) \, ds = \int\limits_0^t u^{(3)}(s) r(s) \, dt = u^{(3)}(s) R(s) \Big|_0^t - \int\limits_0^t u^{(4)}(s) R(s) \, ds,
   $$
   where $R$ is a primitive for $r$, which is possible to find as $r$ is integrable. In this case, as $v(0)=v(+\infty)=0$ and assuming now that $r$ and $R$ are bounded, then
   \begin{align*}
   \int\limits_0^{+\infty} \big( r(t) u^{(3)}(t) \big)' v(t) \, dt &= -v(t)\bigg( u^{(3)}(s) R(s) \Big|_0^t - \int\limits_0^t u^{(4)}(s) R(s) \, ds \Big) \Bigg|_0^{+\infty}
   \\
   &\qquad + \int\limits_0^{+\infty} v''(t) \bigg( u^{(3)}(s) R(s) \Big|_0^t - \int\limits_0^t u^{(4)}(s) R(s) \, ds \bigg) \, dt
   \\
   &= \int\limits_0^{+\infty} v''(t) \big( u^{(3)}(t) R(t) - u^{(3)}(0)R(0) \big) \, dt
   \\
   &\qquad - \int\limits_0^{+\infty} \int\limits_0^t v''(t) u^{(4)}(s) R(s) \, ds \, dt.
   \end{align*}
   The case $r$ regular and $v'$ not regular is almost the same: Define $x(t) := r(t)$ and $y'(t) := v'(t) u^{(3)}(t)$. Thus,
   $$
   \int\limits_0^{+\infty} r(t) v'(t) u^{(3)}(t) \, dt = r(t) y(t) \Big|_{0}^{+\infty} - \int\limits_0^{+\infty} y(t) r'(t) \, dt,
   $$
   where we use the fact that $v(0) = 0$ to get
   $$
   y(t) = u^{(3)}(s) v(s) \Big|_0^t - \int\limits_0^t u^{(4)}(s) v(s) \, ds = u^{(3)}(t) v(t) - \int\limits_0^t u^{(4)}(s) v(s) \, ds.
   $$
   Finally,
   \begin{align*}
   \int\limits_0^{+\infty} \big( r(t) u^{(3)}(t) \big)' v(t) \, dt 
   &= -r(t) \bigg( u^{(3)}(t) v(t) - \int\limits_0^t u^{(4)}(s) v(s) \, ds \bigg) \Big|_{0}^{+\infty} 
   \\
   &\qquad + \int\limits_0^{+\infty} \Big( u^{(3)}(t) v(t) - \int\limits_0^t u^{(4)}(s) v(s) \, ds \Big) r'(t) \, dt
   \\
   &=  \int\limits_0^{+\infty} u^{(3)}(t) v(t)r'(t) \, dt -  \int\limits_0^{+\infty} \int\limits_0^t u^{(4)}(s) v(s) r'(t)\, ds\, dt
   \\&  \qquad+
    \lim\limits_{t\to +\infty} r(t) \int\limits_0^t u^{(4)}(s) v(s) \, ds 
   \end{align*}
3. If $v'$ and $r$ are not more regular, then there's nothing else to be done.

There's a fun fact of point 1: If you expand the answer, you get
$$
\int\limits_0^{+\infty} \big( r(t) u^{(3)}(t) \big)' v(t) \, dt = \int\limits_0^{+\infty} u''(t) r'(t)v'(t) + u''(t) v''(t) r(t) \, dt.
$$
If $v$ is an arbitrary function from certain class that relates to $u$, then it can be considered as a test function. Then, integrating by parts the first term of the equation above
$$
\int\limits_0^{+\infty} u''(t) r'(t) v'(t) \, dt = u'(t)r'(t)v'(t) \Big|_0^{+\infty} - \int\limits_0^{+\infty} u'(t) \big( r''(t)v'(t) + r'(t)v''(t) \big) \,dt,
$$
which let's us write
$$
\int\limits_0^{+\infty} \big( r(t) u^{(3)}(t) \big)' v(t) \, dt = \int\limits_0^{+\infty} u''(t) v''(t) r(t) - u'(t) \big( r''(t)v'(t) + r'(t)v''(t) \big) \, dt.
$$
This way, you have reduced the derivation order as much as possible without assuming that $v$ or $r$ have more regularity than $u$. This is a standard procedure when looking after weak solutions of differential equations (: